# yii2 : Fatal error $this

Tags: php, angularjs, yii, yii2, seed

I am trying to run "yii2-angular-seed-master" on my local machine. 
I download it from  https://github.com/seedss/yii2-angular-seed.

But when i am trying to run this URL.
http://localhost/harry/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/views/site/

It gives me following error.

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/harry/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/views/site/index.php on line 3

```
----------------------
code for views/site/index.php
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
    $this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
-----------------------
SiteController.php

<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
//namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

    public function actionIndex()
    {
            return $this->render('index');
    }
```

Please suggest me what's wrong in the above code.

Comment: where is the class defined?

Comment: I don't think it's intended that you run that file directly.

Comment: @Jim.   yes, i tried that file to run directly. But same error.  http://localhost/harry/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/views/site/    as well as   http://localhost/harry/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/views/site/index.php

Comment: put your actionIndex() in SiteController class

Comment: @yatin:- it is already there. look at here 
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use yii\web\Controller;
class SiteController extends Controller
{  
    public function actions()
    {
      return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function actionIndex()
    {
     return $this->render('index');
    }   
}

Comment: can you remove $this->title = 'My Yii Application'; from your view and try it. might be it will be issue because error showing at line no 3. Ohterwise in your actionIndex() action assign $this->title value then try it.

Comment: @YatinMistry:-
Yes right, i removed $this->title = 'My Yii Application', it works fine but there are many pages where the $this->title is used. So i dont wants to remove this from each page. i want to solve without removing $this->title from each page.

Comment: In your Controller class create new public variable : public $title = "My we Application"; then it will be worked

Comment: @YatinMistry
i create a new variable public $title = "My we Application"; in controler.
But same error occured

Comment: @YatinMistry
Nop, Same Error.

Comment: can you show your updated code?

Comment: ==index.php
<?= $this->title;?>
== SiteControler
class SiteController extends Controller
{  
    public $title = "My we Application";
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function actionIndex()
    {
            return $this->render('index');
    }   
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` in /var/www/harry/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/views/site/index.php is an instance of the `View` class. This is different from `$this` in Yii1, where it used to refer to the controller.
Removing `$this` in every view is definitely not the way to go, because this is just how Yii2 works.

The controller will create that View instance, therefore you shouldn't call the view file directly. Instead, call the url as follows: http://localhost/harry/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/site/index (according to your .htaccess rewrite rules, as stated in the readme of that repository).

More info:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html

Comment: I am having the same issue and I used the same URL structure : http://localhost/harry/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/site/index for my local run , but I am getting 404 Not Found error. Can you help me out on the same?

Comment: @TetrixUser it's a different issue, but probably your environment is not set up properly: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers